# Make particule collection retain keyframed movement

Tags: particles

I'm trying to replicate the tutorial from "Animating Huge Crowds in Blender - Lazy Tutorials" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWq-ZPMhai8&list=PL4Dq5VyfewIxxjzS34k2NES_PuDUIjRcY&index=5)

As a TL;DR; this consists of modeling a set of people with a simple walk cycle and using these as particles so that you can simulate a crowd walking.

The problem I'm facing is that, although I see the people move their arms and legs, they're stationary. On the original tutorial they actually retained the Y movement that was keyframed before using them as particules.

I can get some sort of animation (ex: using Boids physics) but not the same effect as on the tutorial, where each element on the collection actually had a different walk speed, which reflected on the particles individual movement.

Answer (score 1):

### Try changing the Particle Settings

I went through this tutorial today and ran into your question when I was following the same steps and seeing that my Collection of "People" were only moving forward in the collection, and not as Particles.

[image: Under 'Collection' make sure Whole Collection is checked]

I wanted to make sure to check the same things I went through to solve the issue:

- Under the Collection of the Particle Settings
  Checking the box **Whole Collection** changed my particles to move like they were in the collection, rather than just marching in place

---

Hope this helps any who see it, checking this box wasn't in the tutorial as I know.

Not certain this is the proper fix but this is from the documentation:

> **Whole Collection**
>
> Use the whole group at once, instead of one of its elements, the group
> being displayed in place of each particle.

from [Blender API](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html)